# autocomplete not working when add row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I have some input when i use autocomplete at first row it's fine
BUT when i use autocomplete at second row it's not working
Please Help I'm tired about this

i try some tutorial here but dont work, what happened with my code

Here's https:*//jsfiddle.net/qxpj0j2n

Comment: pl create jsfiddle and share link of fiddle here

Comment: You have the duplicated id problem. You must use class because if you add more than 1 row, the id will be duplicated and the autocomplete will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the element with the same id and you are using the same id.

> Id must be unique

To apply the autocomplete on all added element you have to use name of other attribute:

```
$('input[name^=kode_barang]').autocomplete({
     source: "cari-barang.php",  
       minLength:2, 
    });
```

Try above code and let me know.

Comment: @Ramadhani your source file is not present there. that's why. try in your code.

Comment: the autocomplete at second row not running